# Unable to revoke a celery task when workers are not started

Tags: celery, celery-task

I am using celery task queue. 
When I start a task when no workers are started, I am unable to revoke it without starting the workers.

When I run this command `revoke(terminate=True, signal='SIGKILL')`. It returns `state` as `PENDING`.

I want to know if it is possible to revoke a task which I've started when there are no workers started?

I've tried persistent revokes but it doesn't seem to work in this specific case.

Comment: Did you test that it is not removed already? PENDING might be misleading

Comment: @xbirkettx after revoking, if I start workers, the task starts executing. That's how I know that it is not revoked

Comment: @SampathSurineni We faced this issue too. I understand this may not be the answer you are looking for, but we just hacked it around with redis. We store the uuids (`task_id`) in a set for revoked tasks and in the worker function checks if the task exists. If thats the case, we just revoke it. 
We use the normal revoke also, along with this where its required.